# How to Call Keys in Nested Hash Tables?

Tags: powershell, nested, hashtable

I'm studying Hash Tables in PowerShell at the moment and I learned that variables can be used as both keys and values. I had already created a hash table by this point and wanted to see how I could nest that within another hash table. So, here's the information for what I'm doing:

I created a hash table named `$avatar`. Within this are the keys `"Episode 1"`, `"Episode 2"`, `"Episode 3"`, etc. along with the name of each episode as the value.

```
$avatar = [ordered]@{
      "Episode 1" = "The Boy in the Iceberg";
      "Episode 2" = "The Avatar Returns";
      "Episode 3" = "The Southern Air Temple";
}
```

So then I wanted to put this hash table within another with the name `$shows`.

```
$shows = [ordered]@{
      "Avatar" = $avatar;
}
```

So, here's my question. Did I write the syntax for nesting the hash table correctly? If not, how should it be written? Also, what is the syntax required for calling a specific key from the nested hash table?

Comment: Yeah it looks fine. Did you inspect the $shows variable to see that it contained what you expected?

Comment: @DougMauer I just did. It displays the names of the keys, but I can't see if it also contains the values.

Comment: E.g. `$shows.Avatar.'Episode 2'`?

Comment: $shows.Values should show you all the keys and values

Comment: @JosefZ, yeah that worked. I tried that exact syntax before, but it threw up an error the first time. Maybe I just had something slightly off the first time. Thanks.

Comment: @DougMauer This is great. It doesn't seem to show the name of the particular hash tables, though. Is there a function that can be called to also display that information on top of the contents?

Comment: Check my answer. Hash tables don’t have name per say, they have key/value (name/value) pairs

Comment: @Doug Yes, but I mean in the context of this, I put "Avatar" as the name of the key to which $avatar is the value for. When I called $show.Values, I only got the keys-value pairs associated with $avatar. I want to be able to know which key each hash table goes to if I were to have multiple hash tables nested within $shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fun and can teach you a lot just to investigate each little part.

So we know we have the first hash table, it's made up of "keys" and "values"

```
$avatar.keys

Episode 1
Episode 2
Episode 3

$avatar.values

The Boy in the Iceberg
The Avatar Returns
The Southern Air Temple
```

If you want to loop over each name/value pair, use `.GetEnumerator()`

```
$avatar.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    "Name: $($_.name)"
    "Value: $($_.value)"
}

Name: Episode 1
Value: The Boy in the Iceberg
Name: Episode 2
Value: The Avatar Returns
Name: Episode 3
Value: The Southern Air Temple
```

You can take each key and loop over them to act on one at a time

```
$shows.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $shows.$_
}

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Episode 1                      The Boy in the Iceberg                                                                                                                                         
Episode 2                      The Avatar Returns                                                                                                                                             
Episode 3                      The Southern Air Temple
```

When you get into nesting, just know you will have to peel back each layer.

```
$shows.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $shows.$_.GetEnumerator()
}

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Episode 1                      The Boy in the Iceberg                                                                                                                                         
Episode 2                      The Avatar Returns                                                                                                                                             
Episode 3                      The Southern Air Temple
```

or

```
$shows.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($key in $shows.$_.keys){
        $shows.$_.$key
    }
}

The Boy in the Iceberg
The Avatar Returns
The Southern Air Temple
```

Or lots of different ways

Comment: A very thorough answer. Thank you so much. You also ended up teaching me about a bunch of functions and uses I wasn't aware of, so even better.